# Using matlab's spmd to compute simple triple integral is giving me incorrect solution, any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Tags: matlab, spmd

Using matlab's spmd to compute simple triple integral is giving me incorrect solution, any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

```
close all; clear all; clc;
% Create a parallel pool if none exists
if isempty(gcp())
    parpool();
end
nworkers = gcp().NumWorkers;
% Define the function
f = @(x,y,z) z
% Discretize the interval on the client
x = linspace(0,4,nworkers+1)
y = linspace(0,4,nworkers+1)
z = linspace(0,4,nworkers+1)
% On the workers
spmd
    ainit = x(labindex()) 
    bfin =  x(labindex()+1)
    cinit = y(labindex()) 
    dfin =  y(labindex()+1)
    einit = z(labindex()) 
    ffin =  z(labindex()+1)
%     locint = integral3(f,ainit,bfin,cinit,dfin,einit,ffin) % subinterval integration
    locint = integral3(f,ainit,bfin,ainit,bfin,ainit,bfin) % subinterval integration
    totalint = gplus(locint) % Add all values.
end
% Send the value back the client
totalvalue = totalint{1}

fun = @(x,y,z) z
q = integral3(fun,0,4,0,4,0,4)
```

q is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your `spmd` block is dividing the 3-dimensional region to be integrated in *each* dimension, rather than just a single dimension. You need to pick a dimension in which to divide the integral, and vary the limits in only that dimension. For example, you could correct things by replacing your `integral3` call inside `spmd` with this:

```
spmd
    ...
    locint = integral3(f,0,4,0,4,einit,ffin)
    ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you Edric for the helpful reply. I did that and it works, but is there a way I can integrate in all three dimensions. I assume I need to learn to use labSend and labReceive?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're after - this division of the integral is into 3-dimensional blocks. Each of those blocks fill the first two dimensions, and the volume is partitioned in the 3rd dimension. This way you integrate over the whole volume. Making blocks that do not fill all but one dimension is tricky, and unlikely to gain you anything.